# How to use a variable in 2 different Php files?

Tags: php

I have am creating a Website that showes Visitors Info. Users are able to visit the page and use Textarea to pick a name for their URL, and the name will be saved as a table in mysql database..

I am using the $name variable in my first php file which is a replacement for the text "visitor_tracking". But today I noticed that there is also another php file and more sql codes, and once again I can see that this file also has the  "**visitor_tracking**" text used in the sql code.

But I think I failed big time, because I simply dont know how to replace the "visitor_tracking" text with my the variable name called $name.

```
<?php
//define our "maximum idle period" to be 30 minutes
$mins = 30;
//set the time limit before a session expires
ini_set ("session.gc_maxlifetime", $mins * 60);
session_start();
$ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$page_name = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$query_string = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$current_page = $page_name."?".$query_string;
//connect to the database using your database settings
include("db_connect.php");

if(isset($_SESSION["tracking"])){
    //update the visitor log in the database, based on the current visitor
    //id held in $_SESSION["visitor_id"]
    $visitor_id = isset($_SESSION["visitor_id"])?$_SESSION["visitor_id"]:0;
    if($_SESSION["current_page"] != $current_page)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_tracking 
            (ip_address, page_name, query_string, visitor_id)
            VALUES ('$ip_address', '$page_name', '$query_string', '$visitor_id')";
        if(!mysql_query($sql)){
            echo "Failed to update visitor log";   
        }
        $_SESSION["current_page"] = $current_page;        
    }
} else {
    //set a session variable so we know that this visitor is being tracked

    //insert a new row into the database for this person
    $sql = "INSERT INTO visitor_tracking 
        (ip_address, page_name, query_string)
        VALUES ('$ip_address', '$page_name', '$query_string')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql)){
        echo "Failed to add new visitor into tracking log";
        $_SESSION["tracking"] = false;   
    } else {
        //find the next available visitor_id for the database
        //to assign to this person
        $_SESSION["tracking"] = true;
        $entry_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $lowest_sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(visitor_id) as next FROM visitor_tracking");
        $lowest_row = mysql_fetch_array($lowest_sql);
        $lowest = $lowest_row["next"];
        if(!isset($lowest))
            $lowest = 1;
        else
            $lowest++;
        //update the visitor entry with the new visitor id
        //Note, that we do it in this way to prevent a "race condition"
        mysql_query("UPDATE visitor_tracking SET visitor_id = '$lowest' WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");
        //place the current visitor_id into the session so we can use it on
        //subsequent visits to track this person
        $_SESSION["visitor_id"] = $lowest;
        //save the current page to session so we don't track if someone just refreshes the page
        $_SESSION["current_page"] = $current_page;
    }
}
```

Here is a very short part of the script:
I really hope I can get some help to replace the "**visitor_tracking**" text with the Variable **$name**...I tried to replace the text with '$name' and used also different qoutes, but didnt work for me...

And this is the call that I used in my 2nd php file that reads from my first php file:

```
include 'myfile1.php';
echo $var;
```

But dont know if thats correct too. I cant wait to hear what I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much in advance

**PS** Many thanks to Prix for helping me with the first php file!

Comment: Hello, I am not reading whole article and not trying to understand what are you trying to tell us, but: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli` instead - for example. Next thing: escape every variable that is in SQL query -> `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $variable);` Using variables through different php files you have to use `$_SESSION`, every page where you want to use `$_SESSION['variable'];` has to start with `session_start();`

Comment: @WigglerJtag, thx for the quick reply! I simply tried to make the php script shorter and deleted many parts to make it easier for others to understand what I mean! I have now added the full page. Hope that helps! My bad, and excuse my bad english! I will try see if I can use your method..... thank you very much

Comment: ok `session_start();` is there, but variables are not escaped!! everyone can make SQL injection and play with your db as he wants. I read ur article second time and did not understand what do you want. I would like to help you, but what is exactly the problem?

Comment: The problem is exactly as I explained above! If you saw my first post then maybe it will be easier to understand! On my website I am using a Textarea for users to pick a name! And when they pick a name the name will be changed to a Database Table, and I am using the $name variable for the Textarea, which means that I am trying to add all the info in the same table using the Variable $name. While befor there was only 1 Table called visitor_tracking. I just dont know how as I am very new to mysql and php!

Comment: As you're very new to mysql and php it would be hard to explain you many things here :) We could continue chat here or some IM.

Comment: Hi @Wiggler. Sorry for later reply! Yes we def could chat which I think is better! I am also new in here, what are the possiblities to chat on here..? Waiting for your reply!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't assign $name to a session variable and use it in your second script?

Comment: @Wolfram, Thanks for the Reply. I dont know how to use the session variable! If you could please explain or let me know how to use it! I got some advice yesterday, but I dont couldnt make it work!

Comment: [Session Handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']="yes";
?>`

Comment: You should edit your original question, not create a new one.

Comment: @BobSort Irigoyen Thank you so much! I will be adding updates after testing it!

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen, I did wrote already on my topic about that I already asked for some help, but all the files were missing! After that I didnt get any answer I decided to add all the files correctly and ask again..Anyways glad to see you noticed it :)

Comment: @Bobsort could you possibly add the $name where it should be added correctly? Thank you! I tried to add it like this session_start(); $_SESSION['gname']="$name"; .. But didnt work for me!

Comment: Here simply after many comments should appear invitation to a chat. But even better I think would be msn/skype, we solve the problem and close it here, because this is not global problem:) Gimme ur IM contact.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to start session in both pages. it should be the first thing you do in page before writing anything to page output buffer.

In first page you need to assign the value to a session variable. if you don't start session with session_start you don't have a session and value in $_SESSION will not be available.

```
<?php
session_start(); // first thing in page
?>
<form action="" method="post" >
    ...
    <td><input type="text" name="gname" id="text" value=""></td>
    ...
</form>
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['gname'];

  //...
  //Connect to database and create table
  //...

  $_SESSION['gname'] = $name;
  ...
  // REMOVE THIS Duplicate -> mysql_query($sql,$conn);
}
?>
```

in second page again you need to start session first. Before reading a $_SESSION variable you need to check if it has a value (avoid errors or warnings). next read the value and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
<?php
session_start(); // first thing in page

...

if(isset($_SESSION['gname'])){
    // Read the variable from session
    $SomeVar = $_SESSION['gname'];
    // Do whatever you want with this value
}
?>
```

By the way,

- In your second page, I couldn't find the variable $name.
- The way you are creating your table has serious security issue and least of your problems will be a bad table name which cannot be created. read about `SQL injection` if you are interested to know why.
- in your first page you are running $SQL command twice and it will try to create table again which will fail.
- Your `if` statement is finishing before creating table. What if the form wasn't submitted or it `$_POST['gname']` was emptY?
- there are so many errors in your second page too.

Comment: thank you very much much for clearing up a lot of my mess, like the sql injection! The coding is def not save! I am trully glad and thankfull! I will be working on it even more now! And the first part worked for me very well! God bless you friend!