# Sharing HTML code between multiple PHP files

Tags: php

I have multiple files that share some part of an HTML code between them, so in order to avoid code-repeat and make my life easier a bit, I put this repeated, HTML code in a single file(`shared-code.php`) and then whenever I need this code, I use `require_once` to include it in the HTML structure.

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this and would like to ask for your opinion.

If however it is a way to go, then would you please suggest me a way to protect this files from a direct access, but remain their availability to publicly be accessed from `require_once`.

Comment: the question is opinion-based *and* too broad.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you should learn to understand meaning in the context, rather than jump on a specific word

Comment: and you should learn how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help do go through that please, thanks.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner If I would think the way you do, I would assume there is no question at all. Way to go, pal.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone are you trying to save some room on the Stack area? *lol!!* you keep deleting comments in questions this morning *heh*

Comment: that's right; there is no question here, just guesswork. Good luck, I'm out. Don't bother repinging me, I won't be responding or looking at this post to make heads or tails out of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share php variables in 2 different php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968960/how-to-share-php-variables-in-2-different-php-files)

Comment: You basically just defined using templates. Why re-invent the wheel? Just use a pre-existing template engine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please suggest me a way to protect this files from a direct access,
>   but remain their availability to publicly be accessed from
>   `require_once`

Add a variable, if it's directly accessed it won't be set:

**shared-code.php**

```
<?php
if (!$running) die('No direct access');

//
code continues...
```

Then in your main application just set `$running`.

```
<?php
$running = true;
require_once('shared-code.php');

//
code continues...
```

Projects like Joomala and others use an approach like this but with constants.

`defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');`

https://docs.joomla.org/JEXEC

Personally, I don't like.

---

As suggested by @JimL you could also move code which you don't want to be accessed outside the webroot.

So if you structure your application so as you have a `public` or `html` folder then you could setup the webserver so that is your webroot or move the files up a level, for example, place them in  `/var/www`.

You could also use `.htaccess` files with `deny from all` in, but to be honest, expecting a specific server like apache2 and not nginx or the copious amounts of better HTTP servers currently around, or fiddling with your server configuration is not portable.

Instead, structure your application so it has a **single entry point** ([front controller pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)), then everything is protected by server rewrites.

Comment: Could add an example with including code that is outside the public folder on the web server.

Comment: `require_once('/var/www/shared-code.php');`

Comment: The point is that the OP is trying to protect from direct access, how could outside webroot code be accessed?

Comment: Moving it outside the web root will deny direct access while you can still include/require it as needed

Comment: Oh I get ya, you mean say you should move the code outside the webroot..

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It helped. Did it with a constant